# Failed to Get Scrapinghub Notification on Slack. Facing Error

Tags: python, notifications, scrapy, slack, scrapinghub

I want to get Scrapinghub Spiders All (e.g *Spider Run,Completion,Error*) Notification on Slack.
I have created ***Monitor.py*** file and ***Action.py*** file and also added spidermoon slack settings in my ***settings.py*** file.

```
SPIDERMON_SLACK_SENDER_TOKEN = ''
SPIDERMON_SLACK_SENDER_NAME =  ''
SPIDERMON_SLACK_RECIPIENTS = ['']
```

But Now when i run my spider on scrapinghub its giving me an error .check the blow error

```
for member in self._api_call('users.list')['members']
KeyError: 'members'
```

**Check Full Error below** ...

```
ERROR: SendSlackMessageSpiderFinished
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/core/actions.py", line 37, in run <br>
    self.run_action()
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 167, in run_action
    attachments=attachments,
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 40, in send_message
    ) for recipient in to]
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 59, in send_message
    attachments=attachments,
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 100, in _send_channel_message
    icon_url=self.users[self.sender_name]['profile']['image_48'],
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 28, in users
    self._users = self._get_users_info()
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/spidermon-288633c-development.dash-addon.egg/spidermon/contrib/actions/slack/__init__.py", line 70, in _get_users_info
    for member in self._api_call('users.list')['members']
KeyError: 'members'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeor.png) 
I did not understand what is this error 
PLease help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you checked this https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#slack-notifications

Comment: I am not sure why your slack settings are empty.

Comment: My slack Settings are not empty , i have posted here empty just for example . I have all settings

Comment: Hi #Kishan I am already following this url https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#slack-notifications

Comment: Let me know why i am facing this error . for member in self._api_call('users.list')['members']
KeyError: 'members'**strong text

Comment: Can you try latest version of spidermon? Which version you are using?

Comment: Thanks ! I am using this version of spidermon -> spidermon  1.12.0

Comment: Can you try and set this field`SPIDERMON_SLACK_SENDER_TOKEN` and try?

Comment: What is the version of `slackclient` installed? slackclient needs to be higher than 1.3, but lower than 2.0 (https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions.html?highlight=slackclient#slack-action) to work correctly.

Comment: There is an open issue to upgrade slackclient version (https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/issues/251).

Comment: Hi #Renna Rocha I am using -slackclient 1.3.2